# Cannot convert dataframe to transactions object

Tags: r, arules

I want to use the `arules` package to practice  mining association rules with R.
The data is

```
datt <- structure(list(Item1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L), Item2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Item3 = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Item4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Item5 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), Item6 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), Item7 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Item8 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Item9 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Item10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", 
"Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), class = c("cast_df", 
"data.frame"))
```

By doing

```
table5 <- as(datt, "transactions")
```

this error turns up:

```
Error in as(datt, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “cast_df” to “transactions”
```

What can I do to convert my object into a 'transactions' object?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forget to load `arules` package.

```
library(arules)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
as(as.matrix(datt), "transactions")
transactions in sparse format with
 10 transactions (rows) and
 10 items (columns)
```

The error is explicit here :

```
no method or default for coercing “cast_df” to “transactions”
```

`class(datt)` is `cast_df` and no coercing method(`as`) for this type.

Note that generally you don't need to do the coercion manually when you use the `arules` package, the function will try to do the right coercion internally. For example :

```
dissimilarity(x=as.matrix(datt),method='cosine') ## works
dissimilarity(x=datt,method='cosine')            ## you get the same coercion error
```

Comment: Thx for your help.But in my pc,there is error with your way.The error is below:ERROE：as(as.matrix(datt), "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “cast_matrix” to “transactions”

Answer (score 1):

for me this works

```
install.packages("arules")
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and it was fixed by adding  library(Matrix)

Hope that helps

Comment: This can be a comment and not an answer. Please read the rules.

Answer (score 0):

These issues are regarding loading the library before the chunk of code in markdown. You have the library loaded in the R environment, so the code works. But for knitting, you need to load the library in the markdown.