# Parsing as.transactions in r

Tags: r, split, ff, market-basket-analysis

I've been working on rewriting my code that worked with data.frames to work with ffdf. I had two columns, and after a lot of fuss I've managed to do a split and get a list with the following look:

```
data=
$A
1 2 3
$B
4 5 6
```

where A,B are the "baskets" or groupings, and "1 2 3" specific grouped items. What I want now is to convert these to transactions and hopefully manage to do an apriori. I've tried the simple

```
as(i, "transaction")
```

which worked well when "data" was generated from a data.frame but now it produces an error:

```
Error in as(data, "transactions") : 
no method or default for coercing “list” to “transactions”
```

I've seen that duplicate items can cause these problems, so I've eliminated those but the error remains.

Comment: just to make it clear the original data set looked like:

    X    Y
    A    1
    A    2
    A    3
    B    4
    B    5
    B    6

Comment: You could improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session (i.e. also include library calls etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be no problem:

```
library(arules)
data <- list(A=1:3, B=4:6)

showMethods("coerce", classes="transactions")
# Function: coerce (package methods)
# from="data.frame", to="transactions"
# from="list", to="transactions"
# from="matrix", to="transactions"
# from="ngCMatrix", to="transactions"
# from="tidLists", to="transactions"
# from="transactions", to="data.frame"
# from="transactions", to="list"
# from="transactions", to="matrix"
# from="transactions", to="tidLists"

class(data)
# [1] "list"
as(data, "transactions")
# transactions in sparse format with
#  2 transactions (rows) and
#  6 items (columns)
```

Also note that you wrote `as(i, "transaction")` and not `as(i, "transactions")`.

Comment: ...I forgot to include arules before the conversion, still a rookie in this area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, it wasn't actually necessary to do this step! One can just send a list as the one described and apriori will try to figure it out! Thanks to agstudy from the following link.

[Cannot convert dataframe to transactions object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923014/cannot-convert-dataframe-to-transactions-object)

I'll leave the question open if someone else needs a solution to it.